# save array with nested arrays on database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm sending a request with AJAX to a Laravel controller it's an array with subarray like this:

`[["ferrari","1200","2","Italy"],["BMW", "35000", "4", "Germany"]]`

where each subarray is a row on my table `Cars` with the following columns: `brand, mileage, seats, origin_country`

I need a little help to start with the saving process to save them on my DB, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($request->all() as $row) {
    $car = new Car();
    $car->brand = $row[0];
    $car->mileage = $row[1];
    $car->seats = $row[2];
    $car->origin_country = $row[3];
    $car->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$ar=[["ferrari","1200","2","Italy"],["BMW", "35000", "4", "Germany"]];



$keys=['brand', 'mileage', 'seats', 'origin_country'];


$data=array_map(static function ($i) use($keys){

    return array_combine($keys, (array)$i);
},$ar);


YoruModel::create($data); //bulk write
```

read of data variable

```
print_r($data);
```

output

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => ferrari
            [mileage] => 1200
            [seats] => 2
            [origin_country] => Italy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => BMW
            [mileage] => 35000
            [seats] => 4
            [origin_country] => Germany
        )

)
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Laravel [Collection::each](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-each) method to perform a action when accessing each element of the array from which you create a new collection.

```
$collections = collect([
    ["ferrari","1200","2","Italy"],
    ["BMW", "35000", "4", "Germany"]
]);

$collections->each(function ($item, $key) {
    $car = Car::create([
        'brand' => $item[0],
        'mileage' => $item[1],
        'seats' => $item[2],
        'origin_country' => $item[3]
    ]);

    $car->save(); 
]);
```